# I can't find the SMD package for a buzzer in Proteus

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, surface-mount, proteus, pickit

I am new to SMD Technology. For the circuit with a PIC microcontroller I am designing, I need to use a buzzer but I can't find the right SMD package for it. What SMD package can I use for a buzzer? I am using Proteus - Ares.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you do board design you need to learn how to build components.  This means making footprints and schematic symbols, and depending on the software, associating them with one another.

Note that a good component datasheet* will show the land pattern that you can use as a guide, and a mechanical drawing that you can use for outline information.

Some vendors have even taken to publishing component models -- it's worth looking.

Find instructional information in the media of your choice, study up, and make your first component.  If you continue designing boards, it won't be your last.

---

* Thank you, @Mattman944, for your comment.

Comment: A good component datasheet will specify a recommended *land pattern* for your PCB. It is often near the end of the datasheet.